# speech recognition lib for linux

Tags: linux

There seems to be lots of support for speech recognition in Android. I have tons of apps the support that.

What is available as linux libs for a C/C++ application to use?

I guess what I am looking for is the speech equivalent version of OpenCV libs.

-Andres

Comment: [not mine](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2010/03/pocketsphinx-0-6-release/), [mine](http://github.com/H2CO3/libsprec)

Comment: Just to add some more details, I only really need limited vocabulary functionality. My intended application only needs to be able to receive/understand a limited set of commands and all numbers from speech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/

or: http://julius.sourceforge.jp/en_index.php?q=en/index.html

Notice that Wikipedia has an article on this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition_in_Linux

and that it comes up as the first non-ad result when you google:

"speech recognition linux libraries"

Research before asking please.